Verifying storage device against silent data corruption
I have a new Samsung 970 Evo which is very likely to spoil the data. There was massive file damage AND NTFS structure damage twice, a week after each time after I installed a new OS onto it. Digital signatures were invalid and I could not even check an event log to see if there were any WHEA errors.
Media Errors count in SMART is zero and full scan in Magician returns no errors. I had been runnning this exact PC with same settings and different SSD for years with no data corruption.
SMART
I would love to simulate light usage with occasional writes and verify data continuously/infinitely, how can I do that?

Questions asking that we recommend products are specifically off topic on this site. You are clearly experiencing problems. Ask us about solving those problems and not just asking us to recommend a tool, and we may be able to help you.

@JoepvanSteen 1) I had been runnning this exact PC with same settings and different SSD for years with no data corruption. 2) It's ECC.

@JoepvanSteen done

It's a new drive? Replace it. Device failure curves are bathtub-shaped. Devices are more likely to fail at the beginning of their life, and then towards the end of their life.

Just show a single screenshot with all the data.

@JoepvanSteen I can check but it seems that unsafe shutdowns were from disconnecting an USB SSD enclosure after "safe removal" in Windows which is definitely different kind of safe.
